# Javascript in Pug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

I have a var in js like this

```
var yezfze = "tot"
```

And I want to return it like that in Pug

```
section.page(id="yo" data-prev-page="where my var have to be used")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tag attributes look similar to HTML (with optional commas), but their values are just regular JavaScript.
>
> > https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

So your data attribute should look like this:

```
- var sectionId = 'yo'
- function prev() {  return 'yo';  }
```

`section.page(id=sectionId data-prev-page=prev())`

Comment: And if I want to use a var until a function do you know what I have to do ? Thanks for all

Comment: I updated  my answers to show the use of variables in attributes too.